# How to create a custom form in NetSuite without <NLFORM> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite

I am trying to create a customer contact update form in NetSuite. How can I do this without using `<NLFORM>` tags? I want to use the normal HTML input tags. Can anyone help me achieve this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you trying to avoid embedding the standard form in an iframe? Are you trying to extend the functionality of an online customer form?

Comment: because i am not able to change the default field type for example NLSUBSCRIPTIONS tag by default field type is drop down with multiple select option i want to use a check box instead of drop down

How can I change this drop down to a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can just go ahead and do that. I have seen examples of people who have hacked the online form code so that they can create their own form (e.g. create an online custom form and make note of all the hidden form fields and action url. Then use those in your own form values.

Comment: is there any way we can change the default filed type in netsuite. (eg:-

    NLSUBSCRIPTIONS

tag by default is drop down with multiple select option.

How can I change this drop down to a checkbox?)

Comment: No but see my answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954762/how-to-change-a-field-type-in-netsuite/38981123#38981123

Answer (score -1):

```
                                               <label>First name</label><input id="445" name="custrecord12" type="text"><br>

                                                <label>Last name</label><input id="446" name="custrecord13" type="text"><br>


                                                 </div><br>
                                                           <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding an explanation of what you have done in the code.